# How to load custom facet in EXM

Tags: sitecore-client, xconnect, exm

does anyone know how to load `EmailAddressList` facet? I have created a custom rule for `EXM` in order to identify contacts I need to access `EmailAddressList` facet but when I execute this code it only loads `PersonalInformation` facet. I know that for `marketing automation` I have to change the configuration and add a facet key but in this case, it did not work. Thank you in advance!

```
private IEnumerable<Contact> GetContactsFromList()
{
    Guid contactListId = Guid.Parse({2986A090-9C58-48B7-C6A2-C2F88FA5B2C8});

    ContactExpandOptions expandOptions = new ContactExpandOptions(CollectionModel.FacetKeys.PersonalInformation);

    ISegmentationEngine segmentationEngine = (ISegmentationEngine)ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(ISegmentationEngine));

    ListSubscriptionMatches listSubscriptionConditions = new ListSubscriptionMatches()
    {
        ListId = contactListId
    };

    IEntityBatchEnumerator<Contact> contacts = segmentationEngine.FindContacts(listSubscriptionConditions, 200, expandOptions);

    if (contacts != null)
    {
        while (contacts.MoveNext())
        {
            foreach (var contact in contacts?.Current ?? Enumerable.Empty<Contact>())
            {
                yield return contact;
            }
        }
    }
}

protected override bool Execute(T ruleContext)
{

    Assert.IsNotNull(Tracker.Current, "Tracker.Current is not initialized");
    Assert.IsNotNull(Tracker.Current.Contact, "Tracker.Current.Contact is not initialized");

    var oper = GetCurrentOperator();

    using (var client = XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
    {

        var contacts = GetContactsFromList();

        foreach (var c in contacts)
        {
            var info = c.GetFacet<EmailAddressList>(EmailAddressList.DefaultFacetKey);

            var existingContact = client.Get(new IdentifiedContactReference("quiz", info.PreferredEmail.SmtpAddress), new ContactExpandOptions(new string[] { QuizInfo.DefaultFacetKey }));

            if (existingContact == null)
            {

                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                var quizzesInfoFacet = existingContact.GetFacet<QuizInfo>(QuizInfo.DefaultFacetKey);

                var score = quizzesInfoFacet.MaxScore;

                return oper.Evaluate(score, Int32.Parse(stringValuee));
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
ContactExpandOptions expandOptions = new ContactExpandOptions(CollectionModel.FacetKeys.PersonalInformation);
```

to

```
ContactExpandOptions expandOptions = new ContactExpandOptions(CollectionModel.FacetKeys.PersonalInformation,CollectionModel.FacetKeys.EmailAddressList);
```

This could solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking to create a segment that you can use in EXM? In that case you don't need to use xConnect query, you just need to make a CreateContactSearchQuery predicate that will run against xConnect, in the list manager.

Below is my code and this is the doco we used for it.
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-platform/en/create-a-custom-predicate.html

First I use a extension to to get the Facet, this makes the code much easy in the predicate. The extension MUST be called `Emails`, which is the default facet key (EmailAddressList.DefaultFacetKey).

```
namespace Sitecore.Foundation.XdbModels.Extensions
{
    using Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model;
    using Sitecore.Foundation.XdbModels.Facets;

    public static class ContactExtensions
    {
        public static EmailAddressList Emails(this Sitecore.XConnect.Contact c)
        {
            return c?.GetFacet<EmailAddressList>(EmailAddressList.DefaultFacetKey) ?? new EmailAddressList();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you rule would look like this

```
namespace Sitecore.Project.Website.Segmentation.Predicates.Contacts
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq.Expressions;
    using Sitecore.Framework.Rules;
    using Sitecore.XConnect;
    using Sitecore.XConnect.Segmentation.Predicates;
    using Sitecore.Foundation.XdbModels.Extensions;

    public class ContactMemberAgeGroupMatches : ICondition, IMappableRuleEntity, IContactSearchQueryFactory
    {
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public StringOperationType Comparison { get; set; }

        public bool Evaluate(IRuleExecutionContext context)
        {            
            return this.Comparison.Evaluate(context.Fact<Contact>().Emails()?.PreferredEmail.SmtpAddress, this.EmailAddress);
        }

        public Expression<Func<Contact, bool>> CreateContactSearchQuery(IContactSearchQueryContext context)
        {

            return (Expression<Func<Contact, bool>>)(contact => this.Comparison.Evaluate(contact.Emails().PreferredEmail.SmtpAddress, this.EmailAddress));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Facets are represented by the *Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.Facets* dictionary in the tracker and are loaded from xConnect into shared the session state at the start of a session. The default list of facets that are loaded into the session are:

- Classification
- EngagementMeasures
- ContactBehaviorProfile
- Personal
- KeyBehaviorCache
- ListSubscriptions

which can be found at **App_Config\Sitecore\Marketing.Tracking\Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config** file

```
<dataAdapterManager defaultProvider="xconnect">
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="xconnect" type="Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.XConnectDataAdapterProvider, Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect">
                <facets hint="raw:AddFacet">
                    <!-- Removing some of the default facets (Classification, EngagementMeasures, etc.) can cause issues, because there is code depending on them. -->
                    <facet facetKey="Classification"/>
                    <facet facetKey="EngagementMeasures"/>
                    <facet facetKey="ContactBehaviorProfile"/>
                    <facet facetKey="Personal"/>
                    <facet facetKey="KeyBehaviorCache"/>
                    <facet facetKey="ListSubscriptions"/>
                </facets>
                <GetOperationTimeout>0.00:00:05</GetOperationTimeout>
            </add>
        </providers>
    </dataAdapterManager>
```

As you noticed, you were able to access the `PersonalInformation` facet but not the `EmailAddressList` because the **PersonalInformation** facet is defined as part of the default facets list.

To load custom facets or other OOTB facets in the session, we need to register the facets key in the `App_Config\Sitecore\Marketing.Tracking\Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config` file by creating a patch of it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
<sitecore>
    <dataAdapterManager defaultProvider="xconnect">
        <providers>
            <add name="xconnect" type="Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.XConnectDataAdapterProvider, Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect">
               <facets hint="raw:AddFacet">
                    <facet facetKey="Emails"/> <!-- NOTE: Taken from EmailAddressList.DefaultFacetKey -->
                </facets>
           </add>
        </providers>
    </dataAdapterManager>
</sitecore>
</configuration>
```

I've blogged down all the steps required to create a custom personalization rule for EXM here: https://sitecorewithraman.wordpress.com/2021/05/02/custom-rules-for-sitecore-email-personalization/